# Nodejs, store bin files as BYTEA into pgsql (corrupted files)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, buffer, koa, koa2

For some reason I need to store some files (mostly images or pdfs) into my database (PG 9.2.20). 
Those files are uploaded by users and when I download them back, they are corrupted.

- I'm working with nodejs.
- The column type I store the file is BYTEA.

This is how I store them :

```
const { files, fields } = await asyncBusboy(ctx.req);
const fileName = files[0].filename;
const mimeType = files[0].mimeType;
const bufferedFile = fs.readFileSync(files[0].path, { encoding: 'hex' });
const fileData = `\\x${bufferedFile}`;

//Just a basic insert into with knex.raw
const fileId = await storageModel.create(fields.name, fields.description, fileName, mimeType, fileData, ctx.user);
```

And this is how I retrieve my file :

```
const file = await storageModel.find(ctx.params.fileId, ctx.user);
ctx.body = Buffer.from(file.file_bin, 'hex');
ctx.set('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${file.file_name}`);
```

The file is corrupted, and of course, if I look closely, the uploaded file and the one I downloaded are different.
See hex screenshot, there is some additional data at the start of the downloaded one : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pq33.jpg

After some more testing I can tell the problem lies into the koa part, when I put the buffer into the ctx.body. It got corrupted (???)

EDIT : I was working with Swagger UI : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1605

Comment: I was testing my routes with Swagger client. When I test by calling the url in my browser It works ...

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `bytea` as a regular text string. You should pass in type `Buffer` directly, and have the driver escape it for you correctly.

Not sure which driver you are using, but for example...

- [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) does it automatically, see [the example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#insert-binary)
- [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) is supposed to do it automatically, which it does mostly, but I know there were issues with arrays, [recently fixed here](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/commit/c2af53a24e6a6bf61fe0f40e5448540dbe9e2d56).
- [massive.js](https://github.com/dmfay/massive-js) - based on [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) since v3.0, so the same story - it just works.

Comment: I think knexjs escape Buffers as it should be. I wasnt sure so I continued to search with replacing my BYTEA column by just a TEXT one. So now I use the .toString method on my buffer to store it and then when I retrieve the data I use Buffer.from (both in base 64) to recreate a buffer, then I return it. My files are still corrupted (with always the same offset as in my screenshot)

Comment: @thesearentthedroids That is a very a bad approach. You should instead inquire how to insert binary data within knex, and keep type as `bytea`. I can't offer more details, as I'm not familiar with knex myself.

Comment: @vitaly-t, So to be clear, you suggest to save buffers in "text" postgreSQL columns? The pbkdf2 in nodejs produces buffers and I want to store it in the postgreSQL. I was searching around and I found your answer. Thanks

Comment: @slevin No, I never suggested that. You normally use type `bytea`, and save type `Buffer` directly, let the library escape it automatically.